# Why I am getting build fail in my NetBeans project when I tried to clean and build my project?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, build

I started clean and build my NetBeans project, but it gives me this output that it can't build. My library JAR files are OK and I have checked all my connections.

this project is palced in local drive not in google or one drive

Here is the output window text

```
ant -f "C:\\Users\\Qadri Laptop\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\cmp_netbeens\\NetBeansProjects\\flatlaf-dashboard-main" -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Qadri Laptop\Documents\NetBeansProjects\cmp_netbeens\NetBeansProjects\flatlaf-dashboard-main\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\Qadri Laptop\Documents\NetBeansProjects\cmp_netbeens\NetBeansProjects\flatlaf-dashboard-main\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\Qadri Laptop\Documents\NetBeansProjects\cmp_netbeens\NetBeansProjects\flatlaf-dashboard-main\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\Qadri Laptop\Documents\NetBeansProjects\cmp_netbeens\NetBeansProjects\flatlaf-dashboard-main\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\Qadri Laptop\Documents\NetBeansProjects\cmp_netbeens\NetBeansProjects\flatlaf-dashboard-main\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\Qadri Laptop\Documents\NetBeansProjects\cmp_netbeens\NetBeansProjects\flatlaf-dashboard-main\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\Qadri Laptop\Documents\NetBeansProjects\cmp_netbeens\NetBeansProjects\flatlaf-dashboard-main\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: I don't see that message tells you *why* it failed, only that it *did* fail. Is there any more information you can provide?

Comment: no sir It does not provide any other information